# Laravel 4 - I want to extract all emails from users table to an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a model called User which contains emails and names. I want to extract all the email from this model to an array. Does anyone has any idea how can I do this in simplest form possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User::get(['email'])->toArray()
```

Also remember that array shorttags are for PHP 5.4+

Comment: This gives a nested array. Every email is an array(1) and then all of them are under one parent array. Like this array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(6) "abc@abc.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(9) "abc1@abc.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(9) "abc2@abc.com"
  }

Comment: `array_flatten(User::get(['email'])->toArray())`

Comment: Wow ! it worked as I wanted. thanks citizenkane. You saved my day :-)